# Can you pass custom props to Material-UI v5 `styled()` components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For example, in `styled-components` you can do the following:

```
const Div = styled.div`
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"};
`;

render(
  <section>
    <Div>Normal</Div>
    <Div primary>Primary</Div>
  </section>
);
```

Can you get the same result with Material-UI v5 `styled` utility without adding overrides to the global theme object like the example in the [styled() docs](https://next.material-ui.com/system/styled/#custom-components)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

##### Yes!

The most basic example of the above would look like this in MUI v5:

```
const Div = styled("div")(({ primary }) => ({
  backgroundColor: primary ? "palevioletred" : "white",
  color: primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"
}));


render (
  <section>
    <Div>Normal</Div>
    <Div primary>Primary!</Div>
  <section>
);
```

However, as [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html) say:

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not have spurious props floating around.

So MUI gave us the `shouldForwardProp` option to tell MUI whether it "should forward the prop" to the root node or not. The above example would look like this using that prop:

```
const Div = styled("div", {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "primary"
})(({ primary }) => ({
  backgroundColor: primary ? "palevioletred" : "white",
  color: primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"
}));

render (
  <section>
    <Div>Normal</Div>
    <Div primary>Primary!</Div>
  <section>
);
```

##### Explanation

The second argument to the `styled` function is an options object, one of the things it accepts is `shouldForwardProp`, which as the docs say, "Indicates whether the prop should be forwarded to the Component". So to remove the unknown prop warning from the console, we tell it not to pass our custom prop to the DOM element with `shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "primary"`. Now we destructure this prop in the function call that returns our custom styles, and use it in those styles like we would any other function.

If you want to use the global `theme` styles here as well, just destructure it along with your custom prop(s), ie `({ primary, otherProp, thirdProp, theme })`.

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-v5-styled-with-props-example-611mt?file=/demo.js).

[MUI v5 `styled` API docs](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api)

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but why would we want to add a logic of whether or not we should forward the prop? would it work differently if we just receive the prop and use it for styling and let the parent component decide what the value should be for the prop? edit: i don't have much css experience so i am struggling to find the use case for `shouldForwardProp`

Comment: @JavohirMirzoFazliddinov check [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730540/12104850)!

Comment: @benmneb, What if we multiple props..

Comment: @HardikSolanki you can filter them anyway you like, if theres more than one i like to do `shouldForwardProp: (prop) => !["primary", "other prop", "etc"].includes(prop)`

Comment: This works, but TypeScript hates it.

Comment: @Gustavo Maximo, I just added a typescript sample at the top. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a fully-working MUI v5 TypeScript example where you can pass custom properties to a styled component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, styled, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const PREFIX = 'NimbusButton';
const classes = {
    root: `${PREFIX}-root`,
    button: `${PREFIX}-button`
};

interface RootProps {
    textColor?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
    buttonTextColor?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
}

const Root = styled('div', {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'textColor' && prop !== 'buttonTextColor',
    name: 'MyThemeComponent',
    slot: 'Root'
})<RootProps>(({ theme, textColor, buttonTextColor }) => ({
    [`& .${classes.root}`]: {
        color: textColor ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main
    },
    [`& .${classes.button}`]: {
        color: buttonTextColor ? theme.palette.primary.main : theme.palette.secondary.main
    }
}));

type OwnProps = {
    textColor: 'primary' | 'secondary';
    buttonTextColor: 'primary' | 'secondary';
    text?: string;
    buttonText: string;
};

const CustomStyledButton: React.FC<OwnProps> = (props) => {
    const { textColor, buttonTextColor, text, buttonText } = props;
    return (
        <Root className={classes.root} textColor={textColor} buttonTextColor={buttonTextColor}>
            {text && <Typography variant={'body1'}>{text}</Typography>}
            <Button className={classes.button}>{buttonText}</Button>
        </Root>
    );
};

export default CustomStyledButton;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using TypeScript, I use utility function for it, so I always type prop names correctly:

```
export const shouldForwardProp = <CustomProps extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  props: Array<keyof CustomProps>,
  prop: PropertyKey,
): boolean => !props.includes(prop as string);

const MyComponent = styled('div', {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => shouldForwardProp<MyComponentProps>(['isDisabled', 'bgColor'], prop),
})<MyComponentProps>(({ theme, isDisabled, size, bgColor }) => ({
...
```

Answer (score 4):

### It is possible

As @benmneb has stated, you can pass custom props to a styled component. And to prevent the custom prop from being rendered into the DOM, you can leverage the [`shouldForwardProp`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api,) option.

#### *"Pain-point"* with this technique

However using this technique can quickly become *irritating* when you have multiple props that you want excluded from the DOM. You may end up with a pain like:

```js
// ...
shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
  prop !== "primary" &&
  prop !== "secondary" &&
  prop !== "third" &&
  prop !== "fourth" &&
  prop !== "fifth" &&
  prop !== "sixth"
// The list continues...
```

Other ways:

### Technique 1

```js
const Div = styled((props) => {
  // Pluck out primary from props that will be forwaded
  const { primary, color, ...rem } = props;

  return <div {...rem} />;
})(({ primary, color }) => ({
  backgroundColor: primary ? "palevioletred" : "white",
  color: color ? color : "black",
}));

// Use as
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Div>Normal</Div>
      <Div primary={true} color="white">
        Primary!
      </Div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

### Technique 2

By default Material UI adds the `shouldForwardProp` option and prevents forwarding props used internally to MUI itself, including `ownerState`, `theme`, `sx` and `as`. We can use the  `ownerState` prop to define our custom props in it and MUI will automatically not forward the prop. Hence no need to explicitly define the `shouldForwardProp`. Here is how you can use it:

```js
const Div = styled("div")(({ ownerState: { primary } }) => ({
  backgroundColor: primary ? "palevioletred" : "white",
  color: primary ? "white" : "palevioletred",
}));

// Use as
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Div>Normal</Div>
      <Div ownerState={{ primary: true }}>Primary!</Div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code sample that worked for me. This typescript sample uses 'styled' from "@mui/material" and 'shouldForwardProp'. I hope this helps.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField, styled } from "@mui/material";

interface StyledTextFieldType {
  placeHolderColor: string;
  borderColor: string;
}

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => {
    return prop !== "placeHolderColor" && prop !== "borderColor";
  }
})((prop: StyledTextFieldType) => ({
  input: {
    color: prop.placeHolderColor,
    "&::placeholder": {
      fontStyle: "italic"
    }
  },
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "& fieldset": {
      borderColor: prop.borderColor,
      borderRadius: "5px"
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledTextField
        placeHolderColor="green"
        borderColor="red"
        placeholder="Place holder text here.."
        fullWidth
        id="outlined-basic"
        label=""
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-torvalds-nc5p8b?file=/src/App.tsx:0-897)