# What is the purpose of shouldForwardProp option in styled()?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was able to put together that `shouldForwardProp` specifies which props should be forwarded to the wrapped element passed as an option to `styled()`, but I am having trouble finding a comprehensible example of its use case.

Is prop forwarding here akin to passing down props in React?

Why would one want to prevent certain props from being forwarded to the wrapped element while using `styled()`?

Forgive me for my ignorance or if my question lacks clarity - I am still learning MUI and attempting to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you're using a built-in components like `div` or `span` and you want to allow the user to customize the styles via some props.

```
const MyComponent = styled('div')(({ bgColor }) => ({
  backgroundColor: bgColor,
}));
```

When you're using it like this:

```
<MyComponent bgColor='red'>
```

The prop is passed to the real element in the DOM tree as attribute:

[image]

And react will complain, something like:

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `bgColor` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `bgcolor` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

This is why `shouldForwardProp` exists, to prevent styling props from being passed down and create invalid attribute:

```
const MyComponent = styled('div', {
  shouldForwardProp: (props) => props !== 'bgColor',
})(({ bgColor }) => ({
  backgroundColor: bgColor,
}));
```

Comment: What benefit does it gives over using simple className @NearHuscarl ?

Comment: I wish they explained it so cleaerly like this in the docs  Thanks.

Comment: @NearHuscarl, What if we multiple props..

Comment: then you check for all of them `props !== 'b' && props !== 'c'`

Answer (score 14):

Already great answer by @NearHuscarl!
If you are using TypeScript, I use utility function for it, so I always type prop names correctly:

```
export const shouldForwardProp =
  <TCustomProps extends Record<string, unknown>>(customProps: ReadonlyArray<keyof TCustomProps>) =>
  (prop: string): boolean =>
    !customProps.includes(prop);

const MyComponent = styled('div', {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => shouldForwardProp<MyComponentProps>(['isDisabled', 'bgColor'], prop),
})<MyComponentProps>(({ theme, isDisabled, size, bgColor }) => ({
...
```

[Source](https://github.com/mkosir/frontend-monorepo-boilerplate/blob/main/packages/utils-mui/src/shouldForwardProp/index.ts)

Answer (score 3):

Built on @marko424's helper function, here's a similar solution with a bit more concise syntax:

```
const shouldNotForwardPropsWithKeys = <CustomProps>(
  props: Array<keyof CustomProps>
) => (propName: PropertyKey): boolean =>
  !props.map((p) => p.toString()).includes(propName.toString());
```

It returns a curried function that takes the property name as a parameter, so `propName` doesn't need to be passed from `shouldForwardProp`.

Like this:

```
const StyledDiv = styled("div", {
  shouldForwardProp: shouldNotForwardPropsWithKeys<MyProps>(["red"]),
})<MyProps>(({ red }) => ({
  ...
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer NearHuscarl's answer on why props needed to be forwarded in react. In case you are looking for a full-fledged example, here is a code sample that worked for me. This typescript sample uses 'styled' from "@mui/material" and 'shouldForwardProp'. I hope this helps.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-torvalds-nc5p8b?file=/src/App.tsx