# Styled MUI Drawer not opening when variant is temporary

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created a styled `MuiDrawer` component so I can add some custom styling the component. I want to use the `temporary` variant but the Drawer is not opening. When I set the Drawer variant to `permanent` the Drawer does show. So it's probably the passing of the `open` prop that is causing the error. When I use the default Drawer component from MUI the `temporary` variant does work:

```
// demo.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
// import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import {Drawer} from './styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function TemporaryDrawer() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={toggleDrawer}>Toggle Drawer</Button>
      <Drawer
        variant='temporary'
        open={open}
        onClose={toggleDrawer}
      >
        <p>Drawer</p>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
// styles.tsx

import {styled} from '@mui/material';
import {Theme, CSSObject} from '@mui/material/styles';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme: Theme): CSSObject => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

export const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, {shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open'})(
  ({theme, open}) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
)
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/temporarydrawer-material-demo-forked-zci40?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @v1s10n_4 answer is correct, I'll explain a bit more the reason.

The [purpose of the `shouldForwardProp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730540/9449426) callback is to prevent the styling props created by the HOC from leaking to the DOM element leading to invalid attribute error. Your `Drawer` has an `open` prop, it's a known prop of [`Dialog`](https://mui.com/api/dialog/) so you don't need to be concerned about the prop is not handled properly here:

```
const Dialog = (props) => {
  // I know this open prop, so I'm gonna extract it here
  const { open, ...other } = props

  // and do some logic with the open prop

  // and make sure it is not passed to the Component
  return <Component {...other} />
}
```

However, if you pass an arbitrary prop that is not from the [`Dialog` API](https://mui.com/api/dialog/), like `bgcolor` for example:

```
<Dialog bgcolor='red'
```

Then it will be passed down to the DOM element:

```
const Dialog = (props) => {
  const { open, ...other /* other includes the bgcolor prop */ } = props

  // logic...

  return <Component {...other} />
}
```

When you are using `styled` to create a styled component:

```
const StyledDialog = styled(Dialog)(...)
```

```
<StyledDialog bgcolor='red'
```

It'd look like this behind the scene:

```
const StyledDialog = (props) => {
  const className = getStyles(props);

  return <Dialog {...props} className={className} />
}
```

That's why you need to use `shouldForwardProp`, to filter out the style-related props (**not the `Dialog` props**) so it won't be passed down to the `Dialog`:

```
const StyledDialog = (props) => {
  const { bgcolor, ...other } = props;
  const className = getStyles(props);

  // bgcolor is filtered now.
  return <Dialog {...other} className={className} />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove `{shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open'}` in your styled Drawer definition.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/temporarydrawer-material-demo-forked-fku72?file=/styles.tsx:817-881)

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: looks like @NearHuscarl already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69809076/9236122)