# MUI5 React conditional textfield error color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to conditionally change the error color (warning orange and error red). I don't want to use `useStyle` because it's deprecated in mui5. Here is my code :

```
import { TextField as MuiTextField } from "@mui/material";

const TextField = styled(MuiTextField)(({ theme, isWarning }) => ({
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "&.Mui-error": {
      "& fieldset": {
        borderColor: isWarning
          ? theme.palette.warning.main
          : theme.palette.error.main,
      },
      "&:hover fieldset": {
        borderColor: isWarning
          ? theme.palette.warning.main
          : theme.palette.error.main,
      },
      "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
        borderColor: isWarning
          ? theme.palette.warning.main
          : theme.palette.error.main,
      },
    },
  },
}));
```

Then I use it like this :

```
         <TextField
           label="Description"
           name="description"
           value={this.state.description}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
           error={Boolean(errors?.description)}
           isWarning={this.state.isWarning}
         />
```

It works but I got this error in the console :

**Warning: React does not recognize the `isWarning` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `iswarning` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.**

So I tried to use lowercase but I got this error :

**Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `iswarning`.**

How can I do to remove this log ? Maybe there is another to change the color ?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69341672/21085480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a style, you can change the `color` of the TextField to get the same effect. Make sure `error` is set to false or it will override the `color` to red.

```
<TextField
   ...
   error={Boolean(errors?.description) && !this.state.isWarning}
   color={this.state.isWarning ? "warning" : undefined}
/>
```

The color property docs can be found [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#color).